# Keeping an elements position when changing it to fixed with window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am changing a div's position to fixed once it reaches a specific section and then once it reaches `#subSolSec`, it goes back to `position:relative`.

The issue I am having is that when `#rotateTextCont` has `position:fixed` applied, it goes out of its original format.

How do I keep the original format when the position is turned to fixed?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#subSolSec').offset().top - 50) {
    $('#rotateTextCont').removeClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('#rotateTextCont').addClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
.sec60 {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

#rotateTextCont {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#rotateTextCont.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  /*left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);*/
}

#rotateText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #b82222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="blue">
</section>
<div id="rotateTextCont">
  <div id="rotateText">Fixed Text</div>
</div>
<section class="sec60">
  <p class="dG">
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
  </p>
  <p class="dG">
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
  </p>
</section>
<section id="subSolSec">

</section>
```

Comment: what/where is `$('#subSolSec')`? because `$('#subSolSec').offset()` is *undefined*

Comment: @Scaramouche Sorry, forgot to include it. Just added it to my snippet.

Comment: You may want to save yourself a headache and add the transform to the wrapper, and not the text element.

Comment: Your question is very messy. First, `offset()` function returns an object, so you have to use `offset().top`. Moreover, explain better what you expect by saying "original format", what goes wrong. The JS code you've added is not clear, what are your condition supposed to check?

Comment: @benams Once you first load the snippet, you see that `rotateText` is positioned one way, but then when position fixed is applied, the positioning of it completely changes. I removed the offset because I was getting an error in the snippet. It must have been because I didn't have `#subSolSec`'s container included.

Comment: @benams I fixed the offset.

Answer (score 1):

I included some dummy offset values for the sake of the example, now regarding your problem you could entertain the possibility of using `max-content` (notice the browser-specific prefix in the code), it is the easiest way I could find, although I strongly recommend [looking here](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) to check for browser compatibility and assess against your potential clients.

**EDIT**

Included commented css to make it work in Chrome. I don't have Chrome where I'm working but according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) it works in Chrome too. Let me know

```js
var reachesSpecificSection = 60;
var reachesSubSolSec = 350;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > reachesSpecificSection && scrollTop < reachesSubSolSec){
   $('#rotateTextCont').addClass('fixed');
      
  } else {
  $('#rotateTextCont').removeClass('fixed');
    
   }
 });
```

```css
.sec60 {
 width: 60%;
 margin: 60px auto;
}
#rotateTextCont {
 position: relative;
 /*margin-top: 60px;*/
}
#rotateTextCont.fixed {
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
 /*left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);*/
}
#rotateText {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: .2rem;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #b82222;
  width: -moz-max-content; /*Mozilla Firefox*/
  width: -webkit-max-content; /*iOS Safari*/
  width: max-content; /*Rest of supported browsers (including Chrome)*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotateTextCont">
   <div id="rotateText">Fixed Text</div>
  </div>
  <section class="sec60">
   <p class="dG">
        "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
   </p>
   <p class="dG">
        "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
   </p>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it isn't really addressing my issue. When you scroll down, the "Foxed Content" still goes out of format (it shifts to the left and appears in a block formation). I want the "Fixed Content" to appear is it does on page load, just to stay fixed where it is when the scroll event is applied.

Comment: @Paul; what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using 
Chrome

Comment: why on earth would you..., nah just kidding, @Paul, that might be the issue, I mean check the link I gave you for compatibility across browsers, just need to include the code from my edit, take a look

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the width issue and the horizontal issue, but now it bounces around vertically. It isn't a smooth transition, from where fixed is added.

Comment: @Paul of course, you need to adjust WHERE it begins to be fixed so when scrolling down, when the top of the screen gets to it, it will look like it got glued to it, understand? it's all about `reachesSpecificSection`'s value in my example, adjust it until the transition from one `position` to the other is unnoticeable

Comment: I believe the issue is that I have a section above the `rotateTextCont`. I just updated my snippet to reflect this.

Comment: @Paul it does not matter, all you need to do is set `reachesSpecificSection` to what ever value you need to trigger the position changing. in your case with that section you mention would be similar to `sectionAbove.offset().top`, quite similar to the value you used in your original js. btw: your snippet outputs `500 - Internal server error`

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to your rotated text.

```
#rotateTextCont {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 60px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rsp7k36/